# Distribution of occurrences of "pairs of heads" in $N$ coin tosses

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say we toss a weighted coin $N$ times, each with probability $p$ of landing heads up. What's the distribution of the number of times we'll see $k$ *pairs of heads*? For example, HTHHHTHH would count as three pairs, as would HHHH, while HHTHH would count as two. I hope that makes sense.

More formally, let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable which is 1 if there is a pair of heads starting at position $i$ and 0 otherwise. What I'm looking for is the distribution of the sum $X=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}X_i$.

At first I thought it would be a simple binomial, with the number of trials being $N-1$, each with success probability $p^2$. But I've since come to the conclusion that it's more complicated than that (from some simple simulations in Matlab). This isn't for homework, just a problem I came across that has been bugging me a bit. Thanks!

Edit: I'm thinking perhaps the approach used [on this website that I came across](http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p145s.html) could be adapted for this, if you fix $h$ and sum over the possibilities for $t$. Thoughts?

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment (if you saw it), as I misread your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Markov process with states HH, HT, TH and TT.  standard methods will yield the stationary distribution  for large N regardless  of initial state.

Expectation is easier and can be done by recurrence. Renewal theory is the term you want.

Comment: Thank you! Hadn't heard of renewal theory, and that seems to be just what I'm looking for.